# How to get the values from inside the code when exception occurs?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nlog, .net-core-service-worker

I have a worker service in .net core 3.1
in my Program.cs i have the below codes

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Handler(ex);
        }
       
    }

 static void Handler( Exception e)
    {
        var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        List<Test> _Test = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test()
            {
                  
            }
        };
        LogEventInfo eventInfo = new LogEventInfo
        {
            Level = LogLevel.Error,
            Properties = { { "Application",_Test } }
        };
        logger.Log(eventInfo);  
    }

private class Test
{
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public string Place{get;set;}
}
```

In my worker class i have code as below

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{ 
  
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        
        do
        {
           
           string Name  ="MyName";// These values will be fetched from different file
           string Place="MyPlace";
        //Some Logic where an exception may occur
        }
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);

    }
}
```

Is there anyway to get the values of **Name** and **Place** of worker class to Handler method in program class when an exception arises. Since I'm thinking of a global exception handler I'm thinking of not putting any more try catch blocks. I want to handle all the exception with the try catch in the program.cs file. How can i get the Name and Place values onto my handler on such scenario so that it can be logged?

Comment: Why not just pass the `logger` to the `Worker` and log the `Name` & `Place` values on each loop? When an exception occurs, the log will have the values just prior to the exception being logged.

Comment: You do realize that the way you want to implement the exception handling your app will terminate when the first exception is thrown? Just add exception handling at different places so you have access to the context. Global exception handling should be the last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a custom exception is a possibility, you could also simply decorate any exception thrown inside your service with those properties using the `Data` property:

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    do
    {
        string Name = "MyName";
        string Place = "MyPlace";

        try
        {
            //Some Logic where an exception may occur
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.Data["Name"] = Name;
            e.Data["Place"] = Place;
            throw;
        }
    }
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Exception class where you can set Name & Place as properties.
In the Worker, add a try catch block around the code that may throw an exception. Create and throw your custom exception, setting the original exception as the InnerException (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=net-6.0)

Then in your handler get the name / place from the wrapper exception, and then use the InnerException for the rest.